# Why alert(~5); output = -6?

Tags: javascript, jquery

when I use ~ before any number it gives output as -ve value but why extra -1?
Example :

```
alert(~0) output = -1
alert(~1) output = -2
alert(~3) output = -4
alert(~4) output = -5
alert(~5) output = -6
```

any one, please share your views.

Comment: Google "two's complement arithmetic"

Comment: Because the `~` operator is not the `-` operator.